# Filter data frame matching all values of a vector

Tags: r

I want to filter data frame `x` by including `ID`s that contain rows for `Hour` that match ***all*** values of `testVector`.

```
ID <- c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C')
Hour <- c('0','2','5','6','9','0','2','5','6','0','2')

x <- data.frame(ID, Hour)
x
   ID Hour
1   A    0
2   A    2
3   A    5
4   A    6
5   A    9
6   B    0
7   B    2
8   B    5
9   B    6
10  C    0
11  C    2

testVector <- c('0','2','5')
```

The solution should yield the following data frame:

```
x
       ID Hour
    1   A    0
    2   A    2
    3   A    5
    4   A    6
    5   A    9
    6   B    0
    7   B    2
    8   B    5
    9   B    6
```

All values of `ID` C were dropped because it was missing `Hour` 5. Note that I want to keep all values of `Hour` for `ID`s that match `testVector`.

A dplyr solution would be ideal, but any solution is welcome.

Based on other related questions on SO, I'm guessing I need some combination of `%in%` and `all`, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another `dplyr` solution without ever leaving the pipe:

```
ID <- c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','C','C')
Hour <- c('0','2','5','6','9','0','2','5','6','0','2')

x <- data.frame(ID, Hour)

testVector <- c('0','2','5')

x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(contains = Hour %in% testVector) %>%
  summarise(all = sum(contains)) %>%
  filter(all > 2) %>%
  select(-all) %>%
  inner_join(x)

##       ID   Hour
##   <fctr> <fctr>
## 1      A      0
## 2      A      2
## 3      A      5
## 4      A      6
## 5      A      9
## 6      B      0
## 7      B      2
## 8      B      5
## 9      B      6
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why not `x %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(all(testVector %in% Hour))`?

Comment: @Frank yes, much simpler!

Answer (score 4):

Your combination of `%in%` and `all` sounds promising, in base R you could use those to your advantage as follows:

```
to_keep = sapply(lapply(split(x,x$ID),function(x) {unique(x$Hour)}), 
                                              function(x) {all(testVector %in% x)})
x = x[x$ID %in% names(to_keep)[to_keep],]
```

Or similiarly, but skipping an unneccessary lapply and more efficient as per d.b. in the comments:

```
temp = sapply(split(x, x$ID), function(a) all(testVector %in% a$Hour))
x[temp[match(x$ID, names(temp))],]
```

Output:

```
  ID Hour
1  A    0
2  A    2
3  A    5
4  A    6
5  A    9
6  B    0
7  B    2
8  B    5
9  B    6
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also `temp = sapply(split(x, x$ID), function(a) all(testVector %in% a$Hour)); x[temp[match(x$ID, names(temp))],]`

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain to me how your code works? In particular, I don't get how the nested lapply/sapply works.

Comment: @holastello, I will explain d.b.'s version: First, we split the dataframe in groups based on the x$ID column. Then, we loop over that list with sapply, and use the function after `function(a)` to test if all elements from testVector are also in a$Hour. I hope that explains it, if not let me know! In my solution, I used another lapply to get the unique values first, but that is unnecessary.

Comment: @d.b. that is a cleaner solution, thanks for sharing! I added it to my answer, if you are okay with that. That's why I enjoy stack overflow, it's a great place to learn from others.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `table` from `base R`

```
i1 <- !rowSums(table(x)[, testVector]==0)
subset(x, ID %in% names(i1)[i1])
#   ID Hour
#1  A    0
#2  A    2
#3  A    5
#4  A    6
#5  A    9
#6  B    0
#7  B    2
#8  B    5
#9  B    6
```

---

Or this can be done with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[, .SD[all(testVector %in% Hour)], ID]
#    ID Hour
#1:  A    0
#2:  A    2
#3:  A    5
#4:  A    6
#5:  A    9
#6:  B    0
#7:  B    2
#8:  B    5
#9:  B    6
```