# Filter dataframe matching all values of a vector in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598397/filter-data-frame-matching-all-values-of-a-vector/45598478#45598478) with Python.

```
ID = np.concatenate((np.repeat("A",5),
                    np.repeat("B",4), 
                    np.repeat("C",2)))
Hour = np.array([0,2,5,6,9,0,2,5,6,0,2])
testVector = [0,2,5]    
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : ID, 'Hour': Hour})
```

We group the rows by `ID`, then we want to remove all rows from `df` where not all values in `testVector` are found in the column `Hour` of that group. We could achieve that as follows:

```
def all_in(x,y):
    return all([z in list(x) for z in y])

to_keep = df.groupby(by='ID')['Hour'].aggregate(lambda x: all_in(x,testVector))
to_keep = list(to_keep[to_keep].index)
df = df[df['ID'].isin(to_keep)]
```

I want to make this code as short and efficient as possible. Any suggestions for improvements or alternative solution approaches?

Comment: Hmm, do you want fastest solution? What is size of your dataframe?

Comment: @Jezrael, the main purpose of this endeavor is to improve my Python coding.  So thanks for your answer, learned something new from that one as well ;)

Comment: I test timings and `ayhan` s solution seems fastest :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [99]: test_set = set(testVector)

In [100]: df.loc[df.groupby('ID').Hour.transform(lambda x: set(x) & test_set == test_set)]
Out[100]:
   Hour ID
0     0  A
1     2  A
2     5  A
3     6  A
4     9  A
5     0  B
6     2  B
7     5  B
8     6  B
```

**Explanation:**

in the `lambda x: set(x) & test_set == test_set)` function we create a set of `Hour` values for each group:

```
In [104]: df.groupby('ID').Hour.apply(lambda x: set(x))
Out[104]:
ID
A    {0, 2, 5, 6, 9}
B       {0, 2, 5, 6}
C             {0, 2}
Name: Hour, dtype: object
```

Then we do set intersection with the `test_set`:

```
In [105]: df.groupby('ID').Hour.apply(lambda x: set(x) & test_set)
Out[105]:
ID
A    {0, 2, 5}
B    {0, 2, 5}
C       {0, 2}
Name: Hour, dtype: object
```

and compare it with the `test_set` again:

```
In [106]: df.groupby('ID').Hour.apply(lambda x: set(x) & test_set == test_set)
Out[106]:
ID
A     True
B     True
C    False
Name: Hour, dtype: bool
```

PS I used `.apply()` instead of `.transform` just for showing how it works.

But we need to use transform in order to use boolean indexing later on:

```
In [107]: df.groupby('ID').Hour.transform(lambda x: set(x) & test_set == test_set)
Out[107]:
0      True
1      True
2      True
3      True
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9     False
10    False
Name: Hour, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks! Would you mind explaining what the lambda function here does exactly?

Comment: @Florian, I hope it got better now... ;-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was confused because of the sequence of operators, `test_set == test_set` looks strange. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Create `set`s for each `ID` from `Hour` column first. Then [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) for new `Series` which is compared with vector:

```
df = df[df['ID'].map(df.groupby(by='ID')['Hour'].apply(set)) >= set(testVector)]
print (df)
   Hour ID
0     0  A
1     2  A
2     5  A
3     6  A
4     9  A
5     0  B
6     2  B
7     5  B
8     6  B
```

**Timings**:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': np.random.randint(200, size=N),
                   'Hour': np.random.choice(range(10000),N)})
print (df)
testVector = [0,2,5] 

test_set = set(testVector)
s = pd.Series(testVector)

#maxu sol
In [259]: %timeit (df.loc[df.groupby('ID').Hour.transform(lambda x: set(x) & test_set == test_set)])
1 loop, best of 3: 356 ms per loop

#jez sol
In [260]: %timeit (df[df['ID'].map(df.groupby(by='ID')['Hour'].apply(set)) >= set(testVector)])
1 loop, best of 3: 462 ms per loop

#ayhan sol1
In [261]: %timeit (df[df.groupby('ID')['Hour'].transform(lambda x: s.isin(x).all())])
1 loop, best of 3: 300 ms per loop

#ayhan sol2
In [263]: %timeit (df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: s.isin(x['Hour']).all()))
1 loop, best of 3: 211 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to MaxU's solution but I used a Series instead of a set:

```
testVector = pd.Series(testVector)
df[df.groupby('ID')['Hour'].transform(lambda x: testVector.isin(x).all())]
Out: 
   Hour ID
0     0  A
1     2  A
2     5  A
3     6  A
4     9  A
5     0  B
6     2  B
7     5  B
8     6  B
```

Filter might be more idiomatic here though:

```
df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda x: testVector.isin(x['Hour']).all())
Out: 
   Hour ID
0     0  A
1     2  A
2     5  A
3     6  A
4     9  A
5     0  B
6     2  B
7     5  B
8     6  B
```

Comment: Thanks! nice solution.

Comment: It seems fastest solution is last ;)