# match all occurrences in data frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, match, sapply

I'm trying to do something similar as in this post here: [Extract rows for the first occurrence of a variable in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19944334/extract-rows-for-the-first-occurrence-of-a-variable-in-a-data-frame) but extract all occurrences, not just the first.

Here is a simplified example:
I have this data frame called toDrop

```
Gene   Taxa
123    A
327    B
445    D
557    A
789    E
123    B
557    C
```

Here's my code that uses match and thus returns the first match only. I'm running this inside a loop so modifying things here for simplicity.

```
Gene <- c("123", "327", "445", "557", "789", "123", "557")
Taxa <- c("A", "B", "D", "A", "E", "B", "C")
toDrop <- data.frame(Gene, Taxa)
Temp <- list()
geneNameTemp <- "123"
toDrop[match(geneNameTemp, toDrop$Gene), 2] -> Temp
```

In this example, Temp should return a list of "A" and "B"
I think I need to use lapply as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598397/filter-data-frame-matching-all-values-of-a-vector) but can't figure it out from that example. 
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. One way in base R that is close to what you've already got is `which()` combined with `%in%`

```
Gene <- c("123", "327", "445", "557", "789", "123", "557")
Taxa <- c("A", "B", "D", "A", "E", "B", "C")
toDrop <- data.frame(Gene, Taxa)
Temp <- list()
geneNameTemp <- "123"
Temp <- as.list(toDrop[which(toDrop$Gene %in% geneNameTemp),2])
Temp
# [[1]]
# [1] A
# Levels: A B C D E
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] B
# Levels: A B C D E
```

Will return a list with the two factors. This method can be expanded to vector geneNameTemp, but it will include duplicates if there are any

```
Gene <- c("123", "327", "445", "557", "789", "123", "557")
Taxa <- c("A", "B", "D", "A", "E", "B", "C")
toDrop <- data.frame(Gene, Taxa)
Temp <- list()
geneNameTemp <- c("123", "327")
Temp <- as.list(toDrop[which(toDrop$Gene %in% geneNameTemp),2])
Temp
# [[1]]
# [1] A
# Levels: A B C D E
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] B
# Levels: A B C D E
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] B
# Levels: A B C D E
```

If you only need a vector with the factors you can remove `as.list()`. If you want to remove the duplicates you can use `unique(toDrop[which(toDrop$Gene %in% geneNameTemp),2])`.

Comment: Excellent! This is what I was looking for. One edit though it should read ```toDrop[which(toDrop$Gene %in% geneNameTemp),2]``` You need the dataframe before Gene. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

```r
Gene <- c("123", "327", "445", "557", "789", "123", "557")
Taxa <- c("A", "B", "D", "A", "E", "B", "C")
toDrop <- data.frame(Gene, Taxa, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Many ways to do that. With `data.table` it is easy to split a column by value and return a list. Since you are only interested in `Taxa` column, you can do the following:

```r
library(data.table)
lapply(
  split(setDT(toDrop), by = "Gene"), function(d) d[['Taxa']]
)

$`123`
[1] "A" "B"

$`327`
[1] "B"

$`445`
[1] "D"

$`557`
[1] "A" "C"

$`789`
[1] "E"
```

Comment: Okay, but I'm still confused how I use your answer in a loop using geneNameTemp as in my example?

Comment: I don't know since you did not gave a reproducible example of what you want to do after. Making a subset afterwards is not precise enough to be able to help you. What is the structure of the other dataframe ?

Comment: Downstream should not apply to the question as written. Given my data frame provided (toDrop) how can I use geneNameTemp to match to  toDrop$Gene get the list of "A" and "B"? Not just the first occurrence using match?